# Angular2 Module x.module has no exported member NavComponent

Tags: angular

I am having some problems with rc.5 of angular2. 
I have NgModule called xModule where I declare NavComponent and I export NavComponent. It is in file x.module.ts

Now in yModule I import xModule and try to export NavComponent (from xModule). 
In the top of the file I import NavComponent from '../x.module'. And this is a place I am getting the error.

```
error TS2305: Module x.module has no exported member NavComponent
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try exporting xModule from yModule, not only the NavComponent